# In Javascript, how do I trigger a local file load via an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I have an app where I can load a local file via clicking on a label:

```
<div class="igv-drag-drop-surface">

    <div class="igv-drag-drop-file-icon-container" style="">
        <i id="igv-drag-drop-file-icon" class="fa fa-file fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i id="igv-drag-drop-index-file-icon" class="fa fa-file-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="igv-track-file-input-container-css">

        <input id="igv-track-index-file-input" class="igv-track-file-input-css" type="file" name="files[]" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="">

        <label for="igv-track-index-file-input" id="load-local-file-blurb" style="">
            <strong>Choose index file</strong>
            <span class="igv-drag-drop-surface-blurb"> or drop it here</span>
        </label>

    </div>

</div>
```

So, clicking on the `label` with `id` with `load-local-file-blurb` will present the file chooser. That works fine.

I want in addition to be able to click on the icon with `id` `igv-drag-drop-index-file-icon` to present the file chooser as well.

Here is a visual aid to what the widget looks like:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: I won't be able to answer, but looking at the source for [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) may be of use

Comment: how did you do it for the label ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger a click on the label. 
For example:

```javascript
var icon = '#igv-drag-drop-index-file-icon';
var label = '#load-local-file-blurb';
document.querySelector(icon).addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(label).click()
});
```

But the better approach is to perform click onto file input field.

Comment: We have a winna. Cheers Deliaz.